# vimscript comments in bold if a colon is appended

Tags: vim

Looking some vimrc files I have found that if the first word of a comment is capitalized and ends with a colon, it gets bold when viewing the file with vim, but I can not find any info on the internet or with :h

I would like to know more about it, what it is it purpose or recomendations.

For example:

```
" Author: Cosme Fulanito
" Source: http://repo...
```

Author and Source would get bold in vim.

Answer (score 0):

Lines starting with `"` are considered as comment in vimscripts.

You can change their shape and color by changing the settings of highlight group `Comment`:

```
:hi Comment cterm=bold ctermfg=blue ctermbg=none
```

Concering now :

```sh
" Author: Cosme Fulanito
" Source: http://repo...
```

They are used mostly as header on top of the files in order to give information about them like Author, Modified Date, License, Language etc.

You can still change the view of those Titles by the highlight group `VimCommentTitle`:

```
:hi VimCommentTitle cterm=none ctermfg=yellow ctermbg=red
```